# Setting tangent style in tkz-fct doesn't work

Tags: tkz-fct

I tried to set the style of a tangent as in the following minimal example, but it doesn't work. Any idea why and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tikzset{tan style/.style={dashed,>=,blue}}% This doesnt'work
      \tkzInit[xmax=5, ymax=5]%
      \tkzAxeXY%
      \tkzFct[domain=0:5]{0.5*\x**2}%
      %\tkzDrawTangentLine[kl=2,kr=2,>=,color=blue,dashed](2)% This works
      \tkzDrawTangentLine[kl=2,kr=2](2)%
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Desired output:

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the manual says that this should work and I agree that it doesn't...

If you instead use:

```
\tkzfctset{tan style/.style={dashed,>=,blue}}
```

Then you get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an idea why ´\tikzset´ doesn't work?

Comment: @Anna It is probably a typo and `\tkzfctset` is meant. TikZ family is not a good place to set Tkz keys.

Comment: @Anna I agree with percusse, it's almost certainly a typo. I just looked in tkz-fct.sty and it uses `\tkzfctset`...

Answer (score 1):

My try of using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% axes
\tzaxes(5.5,5.5){$x$}[b]{$y$}[l]
% ticks
\tzticks<-2pt,-2pt>{0,1,...,5}{0,1,...,5}
\tzticks*(-2pt:2pt){0,1,...,5}(-2pt:2pt){0,1,...,5}
% plot functions
\def\Fx{0.5*(\x)^2}
\tzfn\Fx[0:3]
% tangent
\tztangentat[dashed,blue]{Fx}{2}[.5:3.5]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the path 
    `\tikzset{/tkztan/.cd,tan style/.style={dashed,>=,blue}}`

```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tkz-fct}
  \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tikzset{/tkztan/.cd,tan style/.style={dashed,>=,blue}}
      \tkzInit[xmax=5, ymax=5]%
      \tkzAxeXY%
      \tkzFct[domain=0:5]{0.5*\x**2}%
      %\tkzDrawTangentLine[kl=2,kr=2,>=,color=blue,dashed](2)% This works
      \tkzDrawTangentLine[kl=2,kr=2](2)%
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]